# Get rid of MountPointManagerRemoteDatabase on external drive (under System Volume Information)

Tags: windows-xp, ntfs

I really want to get rid of the `System Volume Information` on an NTFS external hard drive to be usually plugged onto the same XP SP3 machine that I have control of. After setting permissions so I can view its contents, it only contains a file called `MountPointManagerRemoteDatabase`. System Restore is completely disabled for all drives (the service is disabled).

So, supposedly, if I can figure out what to do so it doesn't create that file, it won't create the folder, right?

Again, it is an external hard drive (not flash drive), and I do not simply want to delete it (I can do that by setting the permissions), but to really get rid of it so it doesn't show up again.

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to do this?

Comment: @Karan I want to store data on the drive, and I don't want to have MyFolder1, MyFolder2 and "System Volume Information". So mostly "it's my drive, not Windows'". For this same reason I disable things like `thumbs.db` generation.

Comment: Well it's generally hidden and out of sight, so it shouldn't bother you all that much. Plus since System Restore's turned off, the folder won't get bloated either or take up gobs of space. You can see related questions [here](http://superuser.com/questions/242760) and [here](http://superuser.com/questions/73441) - it's easy to get rid of the folders by changing permissions or easier still using a Linux LiveCD, but Windows *will* recreate them. The only permanent solution IMO is DOS/very old version of Windows/Linux.

Comment: @Karan hm, I already know how to delete it, and since I keep system files visible (maybe I'm paranoid but it scares me that something is there but is hidden), it does bother me. But you gave me an idea, of running a script/small .exe every time the drive loads, and delete that folder/file. It's one solution...