# Is it safe to delete the System Volume Information folder?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, ntfs

I have a 3 TB external NTFS drive I was originally using on Windows. I'm now using it on a Linux samba fileserver, and there's a folder named "System Volume Information" on the HDD root. Windows wouldn't even let me see the contents of this folder, it consists of only a `tracking.log` file and a `EfaData` folder with a single file in it named `SYMEFA.DB`.

I don't know the purpose of this folder, nor if it is necessary for partition or data integrity [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/73441/how-to-delete-system-volume-information-folder-from-external-drives) shows *how* to delete the folder, but not in which ocasions it should (or shouldn't) be deleted.

Is it always safe to delete this folder? If not, then when?

Comment: "I don't know the purpose of this folder" then why not look that up? It's not like it's a big mystery. :) [About $Recycle.bin, Recycler and System Volume Information Folders in Windows](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/about-recycler-and-system-volume-information-folder-in-xp-and-vista/), [What's the deal with the System Volume Information folder?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/20/55764.aspx), [How to gain access to the System Volume Information folder](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309531).

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to delete it?

Comment: @and31415 it just annoys me to see the folder there.

Comment: SYMEFA.DB is created by Symantec Endpoint Protection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That folder is for holding Windows-specific files, like Shadow Copies.

If you're not using the drive on a Windows machine anymore, then feel free to delete it.

Comment: When you say "Windows Specific", do you mean that Linux view "System Volume Information" as just another normal folder?, I booted into Linux Puppy and tried to copy "System Volume Information" to a usb harddrive. Do you know why somehow not all the files (the size of the folder is not the same after moving) are copied over?