# Are all these hidden files supposed to be here?

Tags: windows-7

I just installed Windows 7 on a new computer.  After getting everything set up there seems to be an abundance of hidden files laying around in the C drive and my user's home folder.  I also noticed a "system volume information" folder on my flash drive.

I don't recall all these files being here on my last computer.  Is this normal?
[image]
[image]

Comment: To make "System Volume Information" invisible.

--> Control Panel --> Folder Options --> View tab under this Select - Show hidden files, folders, and drives.

Then click 
check - Hide empty drives in the Computer folder
check - Hide extensions for known file types
check - Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)

Comment: Related/Possible Dupe: [Is it safe to delete the System Volume Information folder?](http://superuser.com/questions/763165/is-it-safe-to-delete-the-system-volume-information-folder)

Answer (score 1):

- `System Volume Information` is present in Windows 2000
- `$recycle.bin` is the recycle bin. It contains a folder pointing to the user, and then the files deleted by that user on that volume.
- `ntuser*.dat` is the registry `HKCU`, also for various users.
- `bootmgr` is the boot manager. It replaces `ntldr` and `ntdetect.com`.
- `pagefile.sys` is the swap file or virtual memory.
- `AppData` is where your programs store `*.ini` files and various working files. It's hidden because user data isn't stored there (it's in documents).
- `MSOCache` is used by Microsoft Office. Everyone else uses `AppData` or `ProgramData` (the *system wide* version).

Answer (score -1):

It's actually a part of System Restore, the tool that allows you to set points in time to roll back your computer. The System Volume Information folder is where Windows stores these points and associated information that makes them accessible. If you have System Restore enabled but don't see this folder, go into [Tools] [Folder Options] [View] and click the radio button next to [Show Hidden Files and Folders] and it will be visible.

How many System Volume Information folders your computer has and where they are located depends on the settings you've selected for System Restore.

By the way, it exists since Windows XP at least.

The other files are okay, don't worry about them.