# I have a Transcend external 1 TB Hard Drive and I accidentally moved files to the System Volume Information

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have a Transcend external 1 TB Hard Drive and I accidentally moved files to the System Volume Information. Now I cannot move the files back, or delete the files inside the system volume information. I can only copy it. Is there a way to move the files out of that specific folder? Please help.

Also, when I right click on the folder properties, I do not see a "security" tab. Possible because the drive is FAT32.

Comment: The same topic has been discussed in our forum check this out http://superuser.com/questions/1070798/remove-system-volume-information-folder-from-external-drive

Comment: Following the steps from that link, after adding the take ownership registry, and trying to take ownership of my FAT32 trascend external drive, command prompt gives me the error "File ownership cannot be applied on insecure file systems; there is no support for ACLs."

Comment: Mount on Linux or Mac, move files there.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to do this on Windows. I have two laptops with windows 7 and windows 8

Comment: can i change the Fat32 disk drive to NTFS without losing data?

The following link explains a method to do this: 
http://www.tweakandtrick.com/2012/02/convert-fat32-to-ntfs-file-system.html

But I am afraid to try it because I have important files in the drive and afraid to lose it.