# way to safely remove $RECYCLE.BIN and System Volume Information on ExFat formatted external HD using MacOS?

Tags: windows, macos, external-hard-drive, exfat

**RESOURCES I'VE LOOKED AT ALREADY**

- [what is `$RECYCLE.BIN`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115414/what-is-recycle-bin-in-mac)?
- [what is `System Volume Information`](https://www.howtogeek.com/282214/what-is-the-system-volume-information-folder-and-can-i-delete-it/)?
- [how to remove `System Volume Information`](https://superuser.com/questions/1070798/remove-system-volume-information-folder-from-external-drive)?

**MY PROBLEM**

existing solution seems to only solve for removal of `System Volume Information` on:

- Windows
- NTFS formatted external HD

whereas I'd like to solve for removal of `System Volume Information` **and** `$RECYCLE.BIN` on:

- MacOS
- ExFat formatted external HD

additional complication is I'm not exactly sure how to interact w/ `$RECYCLE.BIN`; seems to be a directory but doesn't respond to normal Bash commands

[$RECYCLE.BIN doesn't respond to mv command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnKZw.png)

Comment: What happens if you just select them & Cmd/delete, same as any other file? Mac doesn't use these, so it won't consider them special in any way.

Comment: very true! guess I wanted to see if there were any known best practices or gotchas out there before deletion just bc the situation is terra incognita for me.

Answer (score 0):

recyclebin is holding the deleted files on the external disk when they were on the disk before deletion. you should empty the trashbin on the mac when the external is still connected to empty that recyclebin.
You can safely delete all mac specific items on an external with a tool called BlueHarvest.

Comment: BlueHarvest seems to be a tool for removing Mac-generated metadata like .DS_Store, but $RECYCLE.BIN is generated by Windows.

Comment: "you should empty the trash when the external is still connected to empty that recyclebin"